# Referencing .NET Core Class from .NET 4.7.2 file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to maintain an existing solution which contains multiple projects.  Two of these projects share the same `Namespace` (SingleSignOn).  Project A is targeting .NET 4.7.2 and Project B is targeting .NET Core 2.2.

Project A is referencing an object from Project B like:

```
namespace SingleSignOn
{
    public static class OpenIdConnectAuthenticationExtensions
    {
            public static IAppBuilder AddPortalSingleSignOnConnect(this IAppBuilder app
                , ISingleSignOnSetting setting)
            {
                if (setting == null)
    . . .
```

where `ISingleSignOnSetting` is defined in Project B like:

```
namespace SingleSignOn
{
    public interface ISingleSignOnSetting
    {
        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating if the setting is enabled.
        /// </summary>
        Boolean Enabled { get; }

        . . .    

        #endregion
    }
}
```

This all works on one machine and I can even use Go To Definition to navigate from Project A back to Project B where `ISingleSignOnSetting` is defined.

This working solution is checked into SVN and then checked out on a new machine.  On this new machine Project A is unable to find the reference to `ISingleSignOnSetting`.  I cannot add a reference to Project B as VS complains about trying to reference a .NET Core project from a .NET 4.7.2 project.

How is this reference negotiated on the working machine and how can I get it to work on the second machine?  Is it simply due to the two projects using the same namespace?

I cannot convert either project to a different framework as these two projects are used on multiple solutions.

Comment: Pull `ISingleSignOnSettings` out in to a .Net standard project so that it can be referenced by both projects

Comment: You say you can't convert either project, then this isn't going to work. I'd be surprised if project B couldn't be converted to .NET Standard though, that would fix things.